# Make Gnome top bar font weight bold with CSS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, gnome, gnome-shell

How can I make Gnome's top bar font weight bold?

I found source for [gnome-shell.css on GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/gnome-3-18/data/theme/gnome-shell.css#L581) that describes `#panel` as the UI to target.

I've tried both of these CSS properties on the panel:

```css
#panel {
    font-weight: bold;
    /*font-weight: 700;*/
}
```

Nothing seems to change though. If I set `background-color: red`, that background change *is reflected*, so I know my CSS file is working at least.

Here is  screenshot of the top bar UI I'm trying to change:

Comment: You probably just need to get more specific with your CSS selector. Maybe something like `#panel StLabel {}` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method described by [@andy.holmes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1108697/andy-holmes) seemed to do the trick. Use `#panel StLabel` for `font-weight` and use `stage` for `font-family`.

This CSS is working:

```css
#panel StLabel {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 13px;
}

stage {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a customized theme under `~/.themes/MyTheme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`. 
It works for me under Debian 10. You may also try modifying `/usr/share/themes/YOUR-THEME/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`,
`stage` needs to be used for CSS selector.

```css
stage {
      font-family: Carlito, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Sans-Serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 10pt;
      color: #fafafa;
      }
```